# Oracle APEX: Text wrapping issue with a display-only page item

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a display-only page item on an inline dialog region. The value of the item is set via hidden page item that retrieves the value from the database using PL/SQL.

The issue is that the text is rather long, so instead of text wrapping, it extends beyond the width of the inline dialog causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear. How can I set the width of the page item to be no wider than the inline dialog default width and make the page item text wrap around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to

- set *display only* item's template to "optional" (instead of e.g. "optional - floating"), and then
- set its "custom attributes" property (which is in the "Advanced" set of properties) to e.g. `style="width:300px"`

Illustration:

[image: Display item width]

Comment: that did not help, unfortunatelly

Comment: Hm, kind of worked for me (as you can see). Could you create test case on apex.oracle.com so that we could have a look? I believe I followed your instructions (created a table with a lot of text, fetched it into a hidden item, set it as a source for display only item).

Comment: I think I know why mine might not be working - I set the value of the page item by setting Pre-text property. Could this cause an issue?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I changed that and now your solution works. Thank you